# Excel - keep common dates

Tags: excel

Column `A` has a set of dates, column `B` has an exchange rate for every cell in column `A`.
Similarly, column `C` has a set of dates while column `D` has an exchange rate for every cell in column `C`.

However, the set of dates in `A` and `C` is not the same.
I want to keep the common dates in both rows and their corresponding rates in the other two rows.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to do this with formulas or *VBA*??

Comment: I would prefer formulas.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [vlookup function](https://support.office.com/en-AU/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) in column E where the key is the date in column C, and the lookup range is columns A and B, use a column index of 2 (so it displayes the rate from column B) and make sure that the final argument is false so that it finds the exact value.  This will return a `#N/A` for dates that are not also in column A.

Next, copy column C, and paste values.  This will hardcode the values that the formula displays.  Now you can delete all rows that have `#N/A` in column E, and you are left the data you want in columns C to E.